# use LIKE inside CASE/THEN in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this part of the code

```
WHERE p.id = m.id AND (
      CASE
        WHEN (c.match_text IS NOT NULL)
        THEN (
          (lower(p.station) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%')
          OR
          (
            (lower(p.station) LIKE '%sealed in%')
            AND
            (lower(p.affected_units) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%')
          )
        )
        WHEN(u.name LIKE '%Memory%')
        THEN (
          (lower(p.affected_fuels) LIKE '%nuclear%')
          AND
```

I get error with LIKE in this (lower(p.station) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%')!!

why is that?

I was thinking this approach will fix the issue:

```
WHEN (c.match_text IS NOT NULL)
THEN (
  CASE WHEN
    (lower(p.station) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%')
    OR
    (
      (lower(p.station) LIKE '%sealed in%')
      AND
      (lower(p.affected_units) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%')
    )
    THEN true
    ELSE false
    END
)
```

Thanks

Comment: It expects a value after THEN, not a condition.

Comment: what about the fix that I suggest? is it correct?

Comment: Do you get the error when you attempt to compile the code with your proposed fix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CASE() is basically a translator: it returns a value for a given set of conditions.  The problem you have is that you are trying to force it to return a BOOLEAN value.  This won't work because BOOLEAN is not a valid SQL data type.

So I think you'll have to implement your logic as nested AND/OR clauses.  It's a bit gnarly but not much more complicated than your original statement.  Something like this:

```
WHERE p.id = m.id 
AND (  
        ( c.match_text IS NOT NULL
         AND ( lower(p.station) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%'
              OR ( lower(p.station) LIKE '%sealed in%'
                    AND   lower(p.affected_units) LIKE '%'||c.match_text||'%'
                 )           
              ) 
         )        
     OR (u.name LIKE '%Memory%'
        AND lower(p.affected_fuels) LIKE '%nuclear%'
        AND ...
```